# Services stopping on domain joined Windows 8 machines (Security Center, VMM)

Tags: service, windows-8

We have been seeing an issue in Windows 8 RP and Windows 8 RTM that is stumping us. The first time each day, when the machines come up, the Security Center service (always), and sometimes other services such as the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Manager and IP Helper, despite all being set to "Automatic" or "Automatic (Delay Start)", all are not actually starting. We have some user reports that it works until either SCCM is installed or the workstation is moved to the local workstation OU, but we don't see any GP settings or SC settings that would explain how this is happening. The event logs aren't showing anything useful as best as we can tell, and neither are the local CCM log files, but it's possible we aren't looking at the right things or in the right ways to see what they are trying to tell us.

We don't see this issue on Windows 7 that we know of.

SCCM is 2012. Evaluating the user or machine policies manually (via Control Panel) doesn't stop any services.

Later boots don't seem to have the issue. If we leave the machine up overnight, then at some time the services stop. The last time we saw that was 12:37 am, and all that is in the logs about that time is the WMI service changing from auto start to disabled and then back about thirty seconds later. We don't have any evidence the two things are connected, but it seems unlikely they aren't.

I know there's a lot of "not helpful" information here but this is the most we have right now.

Ideas? I am hoping someone else has seen this and can point me at a quick answer as users are starting to complain about the issue. Or at least can give me a better idea of what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a coworker:

> I have found the culprit (verified that is breaks security center, believe it is the direct access issue as well)
>
> It is the Scheduled Task called “Configuration Manager Health Evaluation”.  This tasks runs every night at around midnight ... You can not remove/modify the task as it will be replaced every startup from the SCCM client itself.
>
> I guess I know why the SCCM client isn’t supported on Windows 8 officially yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

This was occurring on my Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V host. Every night it would stop the Hyper-V services and I would be wondering why.

Definitely not just a Windows 8 issue (although now that I think about it, I am seeing this on my Windows 8 test machines as well).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2796086 addresses this. The workaround in the article does work.  SP1 does fix it. That is if you don't forget to update the clients (like I did).